# Compiler Warning (level 4) CS0649

Tags: c#, .net

I was just coding a application for making message boxes and while I was coding a feature for saving the message boxes I stumbled across this.

This is a photo of the warning:
[image: picture of the error]

> Field 'Form1.table' is never assigned to, and will always have its default value null.

When i click it it shows me this piece of code: `public Form1()`

I searched on every SINGLE website i found (including here) but:

- stackoverflow: complicated
- microsoft docs: only told me how to make the error

Any ideas on how to fix this? Looking for clear and simple answers or pretty much anything that can solve my issue.

decided to send my entire form1.cs thing because of 1 comment:

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Message_Box_Creator
{
   public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private readonly DataTable table;
         public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            _ = table; new DataTable();
            table.Columns.Add("title", typeof(String));
            table.Columns.Add("message", typeof(String));
            dataGridView1.DataSource = table;
        }

        private void label2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            txtTitle.Clear();
            txtMessage.Clear();
        }

        private void bttSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            table.Rows.Add(txtTitle.Text,txtMessage.Text);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show both the code and the error message as *text*. This is inherently textual information, and *much* better presented as text. Fundamentally, it sounds like you've got a field called `table` and you're not assigning anything to it... we can't really tell you much more than that at the moment.

Comment: This is a warning, not an error. You are safe to ignore it, but if you want to make it go away you should remove the `table` property from `Form1`!

Comment: The error message is quite clear - the field isn't being assigned to. If you think differently, please identify which line of your code you think assigns a value to it? I can tell you that I'm very *confused* by your `_ = table; new DataTable();` line, I don't know what it's trying to achieve but it's not assigning a value to the `table` field.

Answer (score 1):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs0649

The table property from  your class is never assigned.
it will always be as a default value.

You should fix your code :

```
_ = table; new DataTable();
```

I feel like you did not even run your code, otherwise you should have faced a null exception at this stage

```
table.Columns.Add("title", typeof(String));
```

***Solution:***

```
this.table = new DataTable();
```